# VBA code to fill a webform

Tags: excel, vba, webforms, element, fill

I would like to create a code in VBA to complete some fields in a webform. Due to privacy-matters I can't copy the whole code of the form. However I can sent the part, where I'm stuck. To complete the webform it appears I should note something like this in VBA:

```
IE.document.getelementsbyID("ABCDEF").Value ="XYZ"
```

in the source code it seems the element id would be `Agent_name`. However when submitting excel, the webform does not take over the value.

This is the source code:

Agent name:

```
input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$Agent_Name$txtText" 
class="form-control" 
id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Agent_Name_txtText" 
type="text" 
maxlength="500"
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your element ID is actually the

```
p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Agent_Name_txtText
```

Also, I noticed that in your example you provided you used: `IE.document.getelementsbyID`. When dealing with the ID of an element, the proper syntax would be `getElementByID()` (no **s**), so therefore it would actually be:

```
IE.Document.getElementByID( _
 "p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Agent_Name_txtText")
```

> `getElements` (with an **s**) is used for element *collections*. IDs are unique, but `ClassName`, `Name`, `Tag` are collections, which is where the "**s**" comes in